# On whether or not $\sum na_n$ converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If $a_n$ is absolutely convergent, then does $\sum na_n$ also converge? I have an objection with $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$, where it is absolutely convergent, but $\sum na_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, which is conditionally convergent. Can I have another example that also has that property?

Another question naturally arises is whether given a random conditionally convergent sum, $\sum a_n$, then is $\sum (-1)^n a_n$absolutely convergent? I feel that this is a yes. Different opinions?

Comment: I think the phrasing "Different opinions?" is quite... unfortunate. There is no "opinion" to have here.

Comment: @ClementC. lol yeah there are no opinions in math

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **No.** Take $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ for all $n\geq 1$. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty$ (absolute convergence, since all terms are positive), but $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n} = \infty$$
- For your second question, also **no**. Take $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is conditionally convergent; but $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n} = \infty$$

For your second question, even more generally, what you are asking is exactly

> If $\sum_n a_n$ is conditionally convergent, then is it also absolutely convergent?

which is clearly false. Why is it equivalent to your question? Well, because $|(-1)^n a_n|=|a_n|$, so $\sum_n (-1)^n a_n$ is absolutely convergent iff $\sum_n a_n$ is.